# Generate 3 circles dataset with three classes in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science, cluster-analysis

I actually wanted to generate 3 circles one inside the another with three different classes (class0, class1, class2) in python(that is first the bigger circle then inside it the second biggest circle and inside that the third circle). I am only able to generate 2 circles with two classes from the code below. Could anyone please help me with that?

[image: Link of Image for 2 circles]

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl
import sklearn.metrics as sm
from sklearn.datasets import make_circles
X, y = make_circles(n_samples=200)
print(X)
print(y)
plt.scatter(X[:,0],X[:,1], marker='o', facecolors='none', edgecolor='r')
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably there is a more polite way to proceed, but here I show a practical way to do it.

Basically you can generate another two circles with the function `make_circles` but playing with another hyperparameter, the `factor`.

What I do, is generating the same main circle, and then a new circle that is multiplied by the factor value (0.6 in my case).

Here is the code:

```
X, y = make_circles(n_samples=200)
z, w = make_circles(n_samples=200, factor=0.6)

plt.scatter(X[:,0],X[:,1],  facecolors='none', edgecolor='r')
plt.scatter(z[:,0],z[:,1],  facecolors='none', edgecolor='r')
```

[image]

If you want to change the radius of the new circle, play with the `factor`.

The only problem of this code is that the big circle is duplicated (plotted twice), but, since they are overlapped, there is no visual problem.

Comment: The shapes of the circles are great but there are only 2 classes so that might not solve my problem. I need to create 3 circles with 3 classes.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentations of [make_circles](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.make_circles.html) and [make_blobs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.make_blobs.html):

> **make_circles**
>
> sklearn.datasets.make_circles(n_samples=100, *, shuffle=True, noise=None, random_state=None, factor=0.8)
> Make a large circle containing a smaller circle in 2d. A simple toy dataset to visualize clustering and classification algorithms.
>
> **make_blobs**
> sklearn.datasets.make_blobs(n_samples=100, n_features=2, *, centers=None, cluster_std=1.0, center_box=- 10.0, 10.0, shuffle=True, random_state=None, return_centers=False)
> Generate isotropic Gaussian blobs for clustering.

You can not make 3 circles using **make_circles**, but for generating 3 classes, you can use **make_blobs**.

For having 3 classes circle data, you can use a combination of these two functions as the following example:

```
import sklearn.datasets as ds
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs

data, labels = ds.make_circles(n_samples=100, 
                               shuffle=True, 
                               noise=0.0, 
                               random_state=42)

center = [[3, 4]]
data2, labels2 = make_blobs(n_samples=100, 
                            cluster_std = 0.2,
                            centers=center,
                            random_state=1)


for i in range(len(center)-1, -1, -1):
    labels2[labels2==0+i] = i+2

print(labels2)
labels = np.concatenate([labels, labels2])
data = data * [1.2, 1.8] + [3, 4]

data = np.concatenate([data, data2], axis=0)
```

and then the below codes to see the result:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

colours = ["orange", "blue", "magenta"]
label_name = ["Class1", "Class2", "Class3"]
for label in range(0, len(center)+2):
    ax.scatter(data[labels==label, 0], data[labels==label, 1], 
               c=colours[label], s=40, label=label_name[label])


ax.set(xlabel='X',
       ylabel='Y',
       title='dataset')


ax.legend(loc='upper right')
```

The results will be as:

[image]

Another ways is to use two make_circle functions to generate 4 circles but using 3 of them.

```
import sklearn.datasets as ds
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs

data, labels = ds.make_circles(n_samples=100, 
                               shuffle=True, 
                               noise=0.01, 
                               random_state=42)


data2, labels2 = ds.make_circles(n_samples=100, 
                               shuffle=True, 
                               noise=0.0, 
                               random_state=42)

data2 = data2 * [1.2, 1.8]
```

then plot results using:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
colours = ["orange", "blue"]
label_name = ["Class1", "Class2"]
ax.scatter(data[labels==0, 0], data[labels==0, 1], color='red'
               ,s=40)
ax.scatter(data[labels==1, 0], data[labels==1, 1], color='green'
               ,s=40)
ax.scatter(data2[labels2==0, 0], data2[labels2==0, 1], color='blue',
               s=40)

ax.set(xlabel='X',
       ylabel='Y',
       title='dataset')


ax.legend(loc='upper right')
```

Then the results are represented as below:

[image]

if you want to change the size of circle(3rd circle, here the outer one), you can multiply by different coefficients.

```
data2 = data2 * [a1, a2]
```

where a1 and a2 can be any values but perfectly between 0 and 2. if the values are below 1, the circles will put inner other circles and vice versa.

Comment: The shapes are not perfect circles. Is there any way where I can get perfect circles.

Comment: You can change noise values in **make circle** for example noise =0.01.  Also change cluster_std in **make_blobs** (cluster_std = 0.3, for instance) to generate smoother results.

Comment: I have done it for the circles but I am unable to do it for make blobs.

Comment: Why you can't do it? I tried it and it worked for me well.

Comment: Could you please tell me the values of the hyperparameters you used in make_blobs?

Comment: ```data2, labels2 = make_blobs(n_samples=100,  cluster_std = 0.2, centers=center, random_state=1)```. Please replace it with above make_blobs part of code

Comment: The circles which I am getting look like this [link] (https://imgur.com/o3PpmjO) after changing the values of the parameter. But still, I am not able to get a perfect circle for **make_blobs_**.

Comment: I'm afraid make_blobs can generate data that has different classes but not exactly on the circle shape. I thought this is the shape that you are looking for.

Comment: is there a better way to generate 3 circles?

Comment: I found another way and test it. it works well. you need to generate 4 circles using the 2 make_circle functions and choose one of the circles from those 2. I will update my answer. please check there.

Comment: Yes, please. I am waiting for your answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237153/discussion-between-raha-moosavi-and-ytt).